# The "redirect" routing of thymeleaf is redirecting the application to http and not to https when deployed in AWS ECS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-security, thymeleaf, amazon-ecs

I am building a Spring Boot application which consists of Spring Security and Thymeleaf. I have deployed this application in Elastic Container Service (ECS) cluster of AWS.

I have my simple controller code for the homepage which looks like `return "redirect:/login"`. But as soon as I am hitting the homepage it is converting the URL to the **`http`** and not **`https`**.

The whole application is accessible through `https://abcd.com/login` but the **"redirect" routing** of  Thymeleaf is always redirecting it to the `http://abcd.com/login` which is not accessible.

Can anyone help with the resolution for this.?

Also the ECS has one service, one load balancer and one Route53 for translating the names to IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are running with https offloading (meaning, that your spring boot application does not receive the https request but rather an http request, the load balancer terminates the tls connection).

I think your problem is described in the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server).
In most cases the solution is to set `server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE` in your application.yaml.

Comment: Perfect. It worked and that documentation described it perfectly. Thanks a lot.